# Display alternate link text in RUBY ON Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

I am looking to have this link show as "Click Here". Right now it just shows the URL. How can I change the label of this hyperlink?

```
  <%= link_to @post.external_url, @post.external_url, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "Click Here", @post.external_url, class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
```

See the documentation for [link_to helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) for more info about how to use it.

Comment: Please create a new question when you have a new question.

Comment: Also, please read the documentation; these are some basic questions you should be able to find the answer yourself.